# jQuery fadeIn not working on IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

Weird problem this.  I've got a web page that fades images in and out on a timer, using jQuery's fadeIn() and fadeOut() methods.  It worked fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE9 - only the first image ever showed.  After a lot of removing CSS, HTML, etc, to whittle down the reason, I managed to get it working in IE9 *but only if I remove the first line of my HTML file*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

With that line present, fadeIn() fails.  Without that line, fadeIn() works.  fadeOut() appears to work regardless.

I'm using the latest stable build of jQuery (downloaded yesterday).

This is the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="scripts/imageswitch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myGallery">
            <img src="/images/Img1.jpg" id="firstimg" class="active ready" onload="setInterval( 'swapImages()', 3000 );" />
            <img src="/images/Img2.jpg" onload="SetImgReady(this);" />
            <img src="/images/Img3.jpg" onload="SetImgReady(this);" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the contents of "imageswitch.js": (I use the SetImgReady() function to add the 'ready' class to each image once it's finished downloading, so it only ever rotates between fully loaded images)

```
function swapImages() {
    var $active = $('#myGallery .active');
    var $next = ($('#myGallery .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#myGallery .active').next() : $('#myGallery img:first');

    while ($next && !$next.hasClass('ready')) {
        if ($next.next().length > 0)
            $next = $next.next();
        else
            $next = false;
    }

    if ($next && $active) {
        $next.fadeIn( 2000 ).addClass('active');
        $active.fadeOut( 2000 ).removeClass('active');
    }
}

function SetImgReady( $ImgObj ) {
    if ($ImgObj)
        $ImgObj.className += "ready";
}
```

And this is the CSS:

```
#myGallery{
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
}
#myGallery img{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#myGallery img.active{
    display:block;
}
```

So... is the  declaration making IE9 go overly-standards-compliant and decide that fading isn't allowed under XHTML1.0 or something?

Another odd thing that also happens, once the fading is working: On only the first image switch, the displayed image dissapears immediately instead of fading out.  All other images nicely fade in/out as required.  Any thoughts on that too?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with 1.6.2. An update to 1.6.4 solved it.

Comment: you were spot on - latest jQuery has fixed it!  Thanks.

Comment: @NickShaw does the version 1.7.1 bring back this issue? I am having this issue now... with fadeOut specifically.

Comment: I've not tried v1.7.1 yet - sticking with a version that works for the time being!

Answer (score 2):

David: missing title in the head is NOT an error. In fact HTML5 let's skip whole head section and it is valid. According to official W3C HTML specification you only need to have a body section :) so i guess this is shortest HTML allowed:

```
<html><body><h1>hello world</h1></body></html>
```

just not sure about need of !doctype :)

the topic problem is - somehow releated to CSS and display property in IE, most cases from IE6. If you set "display:none" to an HTML element, you get no results with FadeIn as element is not displayed because of "display:none", and fadeIn does not change this state.

my solution is: make a CSS class "hidden" and set as "display:none" as usually. And this line of JavaScript code fired on document.load:

```
$('.hidden').fadeTo(0,0).css('visibility','visible');
```

after that fadeIn - and eventually fadeOut :) - shoud be working now. If you still get any issues - try to use fadeTo or opacity animation effect in place of fadeIn/fadeOut.

Comment: Thanks, @user1906727, some useful tips there.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the DOCTYPE puts IE into quirks mode, you can achieve the same thing by pressing F12 to activate the debug console and then selecting quirks mode or compatibility mode on the bottom of the screen.

I am getting the same weird behaviour though.

It seems to work better by executing the code in debug mode for some reason, or if you attach the behaviour to a button, it will eventually work if you click it enough.

i think the fadein behaviour is buggy, and only fades in the background of the element and not the foreground. show() exhibits the same weird behaviour.

Everything works fine in compatibility view, as much as I dislike using it.

Comment: This is not really an answer or solution to the OP.

Comment: David - thanks for that.  @Sparky672 - David does say that compatibility view resolves the problem, so I'd say that's some way to an answer.  For the time being, I've done a small block of IE-only code that doesn't do the fade, rather just swaps the images instantly.  Not as nice, but that's the downside of using IE I guess. :)

Comment: @Nick, it does not identify a root cause and removing a valid Doctype is no solution.  Have you run your page through the W3C Validator yet?

Comment: W3C validator shows: missing <title> in head, missing alt attrib in <img> tags, "onload" invalid attrib for <img> tags.  Looking up onload in <img> tags, MSDN implies it *is* valid: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197055%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, but a comment there says "For dynamically created img objects, the onload event only fires if the source file is downloaded from the web server. When the file is already stored [in the browser's cache], the onload event is never triggered." That may well be the problem, though doesn't explain why my code works without the DOCTYPE declaration.

Comment: Sparky672, I was explaining what removing the DOCTYPE was doing for Nick, not offering a total solution. This problem is buggy behaviour in IE9 and related to fadein() show() and other effects. I cannot resolve it as its a problem with IE. try running the fadein example at microsofts CDN http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx and you will see the exact same behaviour. It works with EVERY other browser and IE9 in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using older version of jquery please upgrade to 1.6+ versions. There were fews issues in IE9 with older versions. I hope this will fix the problem.

Comment: I'm using v1.6.2, so that can't be the issue. :)